# Best way to include libraries in Unreal Engine 4 C++

Tags: c++, libraries, unreal-engine4

I would like to use some external libraries in UE4, specifically libCPR to do some web scraping. I am new to ue4 and am having a lot of trouble finding out where to start, I saw some [references](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/ProductionPipelines/BuildTools/UnrealBuildTool/ThirdPartyLibraries/) to using plugins to import third party libraries but I am having a lot of trouble getting this to work. Are custom third party plugins the way to go or should i use a different approach?

All I'd like to do is to be able to use a function from a library in an actor class and don't know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!